# Solspace freeform webhook

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, solspace

Just wanted to know if there's an easy way to hook Solspace Freeform submission to external API?

I got a form built using Solspace freefrom Pro, and I'd like to post each submission of the form to an external API. Whats the easiest way to go about this using Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an entire section here that discusses API integrations, including the ones that come with Freeform.  http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/

Comment: Yes, found it here. Thanks 
http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/developer/events-and-hooks.html#usage-examples